# How to save indices, created with nmslib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, nmslib

I am using nmslib with hnsw method for vector similarity search. I have built index class for index creation:

```
class NMSLIBIndex():
    def __init__(self, vectors, labels):
        self.dimention = vectors.shape[1]
        self.vectors = vectors.astype('float32')
        self.labels = labelsdef build(self):
        self.index = nmslib.init(method='hnsw', space='cosinesimil')
        self.index.addDataPointBatch(self.vectors)
        self.index.createIndex({'post': 2})
        
    def query(self, vector, k=10):
        indices = self.index.knnQuery(vector, k=k)
        return [self.labels[i] for i in indices[0]]
```

I was referring to this article https://towardsdatascience.com/comprehensive-guide-to-approximate-nearest-neighbors-algorithms-8b94f057d6b6

And now i want to load this indices to my database to use in online environment. My question is, how could i save these indices built on my vectors?

Answer (score 0):

```
index.saveIndex("nmslib_index", save_data=True)
```

[Official doc](https://nmslib.github.io/nmslib/api.html#nmslib.dist.FloatIndex.saveIndex)